# Angular selector returns the store object instead of the observable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8, ngrx-store

I am working on an Angular project at work. We have recently upgraded to Angular 8. I have a selector that fetches the value that I then feed to a tooltip. The selector is created in root reducer as so

```js
//create feature selector
export const getLayoutState = createFeatureSelector<fromLayout.State>('layout');

export const getTitleTooltip = createSelector(getLayoutState, fromLayout.getTooltip);
```

where `getLayoutstate` is the feature selector and inside the layout store we fetch the tooltip text like so

```js
export const getTooltip = (state: State) => state.tooltipText;
```

Inside the component where we want to use this observable we do

```js
this.headerTitleTooltip = this.layoutStore.pipe(select(fromLayout.getTitleTooltip ));
```

And then in html render it with the `async` pipe

However this code returns a store object instead of the observable. I have checked my selector declaration statements and the syntax is as per what is in the documentation, what am I doing wrong

Comment: The problem might come from the way you fill your state. Can we see how you give a value to your initial state, and if you change it, how ?

Comment: @Mambo You were right .I feel stupid now. The action that sets the tooltip text was removed from some components while doing something else I'm guessing. Our code base is huge, but I went through our code thoroughly and noticed that this issue was happening in only some places and that's how I figured it out. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No problem mate ! Glad you found the solution :)